# Unable to display view inside a subfolder using absolute url

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I'm using `ASP.NET MVC Core RC2` in `VS2015`. I've a controller named `TestController` in the Controllers folder as follows:

```
// GET: /<controller>/
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Mesage = "Test message";
            return View();
        }
```

The corresponding view, named, `TestRel.chtml` is inside the folder `Views/Northwind` as follows:

```
@{
    <label>Test view</label>
}
```

But, for testing, when I run the absolute URL `http://localhost:49944/Test/Index` I get the following **error**:

```
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Test/Index.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable`1 originalLocations).
```

**How can I display the above view using absolute URL**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should work if i use `return view("~/views/northwind/TestRel.cshtml");` or after placing it in views/test/, `return view("testrel");`

Comment: Now, I'm getting the followin error: `An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

InvalidOperationException: The view '/views/Northwind/TestRel.chtml' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/views/Northwind/TestRel.chtml
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable`1 originalLocations)`

Comment: can you try by adding an extra "~"..  "return view("~/views/northwind/TestRel.chtml");"

Comment: I get similar error as above: `InvalidOperationException: The view '~/views/Northwind/TestRel.chtml' was not found. The following locations were searched:
~/views/Northwind/TestRel.chtml
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines.ViewEngineResult.EnsureSuccessful(IEnumerable`1 originalLocations)`

Comment: chtml=>cshtml . sorry for the typo

Comment: `return view("/views/northwind/TestRel.cshtml");` one works. Thank you for helping me.